# How to prove this set equality? (HINT)

Tags: calculus

I have to prove this equality:
$$
\{ c_1\cos(t)+c_2\sin(t), \quad c_1,c_2\in\mathbb{R} \} =\{A\\cos(t+\theta), \quad A\geq 0, \theta\in[0,2\pi[ \}
$$

My teacher has told that I have to prove this proving that the first one is $ \subseteq $ in the second and vice versa. 
Any hint?

Comment: The equation that comes to my mind is
$$
\sin{(x+y)} = \sin{x}\cos{x} + \cos{x}\sin{y}
$$
So maybe if you choose $y$ correctly ...

Comment: Is $t$ fixed, or does it vary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O.K., now we have to prove

$\{ c_1\cos(t)+c_2\sin(t): c_1,c_2\in\mathbb{R}\}=\{A\cos(t+\theta): A\geq 0, \theta\in[0,2\pi[ \}$

Since $A \cos(t+\theta)=A \cos( \theta) \cos(t)-A \sin( \theta) \sin(t)$, we only have to show that

$\{(A \cos( \theta), -A \sin( \theta)): A \ge 0, \theta\in[0,2\pi[ \}= \mathbb R^2.$

Can you proceed ?

Answer (score 2):

$\{ c_1\cos(t)+c_2\sin(t), \quad c_1,c_2\in\mathbb{R} \} = \{ A\cos(t)+B, \quad A,B\in\mathbb{R} \}$ is not true !

Reason: suppose that the above equation is true. Then there are $A,B \in \mathbb R$ such that

$ \sin t=A \cos t +B$.

With $t= \pi$ we get $A=B$ and with $t= \pi /2$ we get $B=1$, hence

$$\sin t=\cos t +1,$$

which is absurd.

Comment: sin t = 0.cos t + sin t, so set B = sin t..

Comment: I think $t$ is constant in the question

Comment: Sorry! I made a mistake writing the problem! I will fix it right now!

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, the left side is a subset of the right side.
For A.cos t + B, set $c_2$ = B/sin t.
If sin t = 0, then cos t = +-1.
So set $c_2$ = 0, $c_1$ = +-B + A.

Comment: $c_j$ is a constant, independent of $t$.

Comment: @Fred.  t is the only fixed number, the c's are in R, range over R.